# When is a Stack Overflow profile automatically deleted?

Tags: support, accounts, deleted-users

Say there is a user which has a lot of contributions to Stack Overflow. When is such a user's account automatically deleted? I noticed somewhere if there are six months of inactivity the account gets deleted?

Why this? Maybe the user didn't use it for a long time or even had some health issues. He has contributed and would like even maybe his name to be there (next to the posts). Why delete such an account?

Comment: If a user has contributions, they won't get automatically deleted. They'll only get deleted if they request it and / or moderators / SE decide to do it for some less benign reason. There are user accounts that exist that haven't been active in *years* but are still around, and that's not even with high rep.

Comment: Details about account auto-deletion can be found in [this blog post](https://blog.stackexchange.com/2009/02/when-is-an-account-abandoned/)

Comment: @Oded: Well, that is my point - that post says if user didn't log in for 6 months account gets deleted which I find not fair as outlined in the question.

Comment: @Oded: or the AND there means smth else?

Comment: @userq Accounts are only deleted for inactivity *if they haven't made any contributions to the site* so there is nothing lost when they're deleted.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/146450/delete-old-unloved-users

Comment: I guess the OP's account is deleted too.

Answer (score 12):

If a user has made contributions to Stack Overflow, their account is *not* automatically deleted after any length of time.

Account deletion rules are available at this blog [post](https://blog.stackexchange.com/2009/02/when-is-an-account-abandoned/).

The criteria you mention (significant contributions) fail the second bullet and thus are kept around.

> the user has not visited the site in six months
>
> **AND**
>
> the user has not done anything of significance, ever

Comment: That's the guiding principle. Though better to quote the mechanics clarifying what's "significant".

Comment: The principle "has not done anything of significance, ever" seems misleading. According to the rules stated there, an account would be deleted if it had, for example, posted a dozen answers scoring 100+ each, then deleted all of them and left the site.

Comment: @NormalHuman You probably know this, but anytime a user deletes *N* answers in *N* time period an automatic flag gets raised for moderator to review. There is also rate-limit of only can delete *N* answers in *N* time I think or maybe not. But either way, very rare that a user could delete so many answers without a moderator undeleting them.

Comment: Okay, it could be 1 answer scoring 100 votes. Not likely to happen, but my point is that the criterion is worded as "has not done... ever" which doesn't align with ignoring the deleted posts for the purpose of this check.

Answer (score 4):

As of a few years ago (2017?), they [stopped automatically deleting accounts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/146452/323179). The only users who were automatically deleted before were [those who did almost nothing on the site](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/02/16/when-is-an-account-abandoned/), but the sheer amount of such accounts made it impractical to keep deleting them.